# Algorithm for determining whether two real quadratic numbers are equivalent under a modular transformation

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ be an algebraic number.
If the minimal plynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has degree $2$, we say $\alpha$ is a quadratic number.
Then $\alpha$ is a root of a unique polynomial $ax^2 + bx + c \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $a > 0$ and gcd$(a, b, c) = 1$.
$D = b^2 - 4ac$ is called the discriminant of $\alpha$.
Since $D \equiv b^2$ (mod $4$), $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
Conversly suppose $D$ is a non-square integer such that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$). Then there exists a quadratic number $\alpha$ whose discriminant is $D$.

Let $\Gamma = SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.
Let $\sigma = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
p & q \\
r & s \end{array} \right)$ be an element of $\Gamma$.
Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$.
Suppose $rz + s \ne 0$.
We write $$\sigma z = \frac{pz + q}{rz + s}$$
Let $D \gt 0$ be a non-square integer such that $D \equiv 0$ (mod $4$) or $D \equiv 1$ (mod $4$).
We denote by $\mathfrak{RQ}(D)$ the set of real quadratic numbers of discriminant $D$.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571126/discriminant-of-a-quadratic-number), $\mathfrak{RQ}(D)$ is $\Gamma$-invariant.
The following question is a *real* version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572583/algorithm-for-determining-whether-two-imaginary-quadratic-numbers-are-equivalent).

**My question**
Let $\alpha, \beta$ be *explicitly* given elements of $\mathfrak{RQ}(D)$.
Is there algorithm for solving the following problems?
If yes, what is it?

1. Determine whether there exists $\sigma \in \Gamma$ such that $\alpha = \sigma \beta$.
2. If there exists such $\sigma$, determine the set $\{\sigma \in \Gamma\ |\ \alpha = \sigma \beta\}$.